# How do I set NBT data on an entity with Forge?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am using Minecraft Forge. I have created an entity like:

```java
BlockPos location = ...;
Entity e = EntityType.FALLING_BLOCK.create(level);
e.setPos(location.getX(), location.getY(), location.getZ());
level.addFreshEntity(e);
```

How can I set NBT tags (like BlockState, Time, etc.) on my entity?

I have tried looking on the Internet, but most of the instructions there are outdated. I tried looking though the Entity class, but the only thing that seems related to what I want to do is "getEntityData", and I don't know how to use that.

I *don't* want to set NBT data on items or blocks, and I *don't* want to create new NBT tags. I just want to modify the ones that are already there.